# Passing a Y command when using Nid

Tags: shell-script

Creating a script to automate cloning process where a command utility is run to change the database name, but i don't know how to pass the Y command when the script runs in the background.

I want the script to automatically provide answer Y as mentioned below.

Example

```
Change database ID and database name PROD to Test? (Y/[N]) => Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your scripts *questions* should always be answer with `y`:

You can use the `yes` command:

```
yes | your-script.sh
```

If your script execute another command, which needs the `y` as input, You can also modify your script, and replace the line which holds the `external-command` with `yes | external-command`

> [man yes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes)
>
> yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
>
> Description Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or
>   '**y**'.